# Dynamic Language Features and Meta-Programming Used in Django

Tags: python, django, metaprogramming, dynamic-languages

Any good summary articles of the dynamic language and meta-programming features of Python that get utilized by Django? Or can we build that out here? Setting this up as a wiki-style entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marty Alchin (Gulopine) has a few articles on various bits of Django internals - including metaclasses and descriptors - on his blog:
http://martyalchin.com/categories/django/

Comment: +1 cool. I'll look into that. Maybe expand my question (improve entry).